# Difflib SequenceMatcher - how to determine 'equal' for similarity of more than one char?

Tags: python, difflib

I wrote a Python module that diffs between two HTML source codes. 
I have a little problem to compare the text - the `difflib.SequenceMatcher` function determines text as 'equal' even if only one character if similar.
So genereted values like "123456" and "abc1de" will categorized as inserted "abc", equals on 1=1 and replaced 23456 in de.

In conclusion, how can I determine that the 'equal' classification will be set only if the equal length will be more than 3 chars?

Comment: I posted a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965748/how-to-set-custom-ratio-for-difflibs-compare-function) but still found no answer. So, I think you have to handle that manually.